# How to remove commas from json object displayed in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I just want to remove commas from object displayed in DOM. Actually, I'm getting

```
,,,TEST STATUS GREEN,,TEST STATUS GREEN,
```

in my page with below code:

```
var vitalTest = document.getElementById("vitalComments").innerHTML = systemList[0].comments;
```

Comment: what is expected output and what you tried ?

Comment: i expected: TEST STATUS GREEN TEST STATUS GREEN

Comment: Maybe you should display it as a table or list, not just plain text.

Comment: Can you give us the actual structure of the "JSON object"?  What you are showing there is simply a string.

Comment: How you are getting  this `,,,TEST STATUS GREEN,,TEST STATUS GREEN,` ? source and method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you just want to remove the commas:

```
systemList[0].comments.join("");
```

if you want to add space in between values:

```
systemList[0].comments.join(" ");
```

if you want to add anything in between values:

```
systemList[0].comments.join("anything");
```

reference for using .join() function:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Comment: He wants a space between them.

Comment: `systemList[0].comments.join(" ");`

Comment: I know that. You should put it in the answer.

Comment: lets wait 6 mins per page request and ill accept your answer

Comment: This is actually not a very extensible answer . . . the only reason why it is working is because browsers strip out extra spaces in HTML text when rendering the page. If you were to put the result of the `join` in an input field, an alert, a console log . . . anything that does not trim extra spaces, the results would show 3 spaces at the beginning of the string and two between "GREEN" and "TEST".

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer using one of this two methods:

```js
var text = ',,,TEST STATUS GREEN,,TEST STATUS GREEN,';
var result1 = text.replace(/,/g,'')
console.log(result1)

var result2 = text.split(',').join('')
console.log(result2)
```

Greetings :)